# How to make initial subdomain using mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

my DocumentRoot folder contains subdomains like:

```
mainDomain -contains-> index.php
subDomain1 -contains-> index.php
subDomain2 -contains-> index.php
```

And i want to make mainDomain directory as initial directory. For e.g. i get it content with url http:/example.com and get the content of subdomains as http:/subDomain1.example.com.

Currently i forced to move all subdomain folders to mainDomain to get the result, like:

```
mainDomain
- subDomain1
- subDomain2
- index.php
```

...but i want to separate the folders :(

Here's my current VirtualHost settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((.*)\.)example.com$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) /%2/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

What have i to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a separate virtual host for each subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain1
    ServerName subdomain1.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

For each of your subdomains.

And remove the:

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

line from your main vhost, and all the rewrite rules.